# Coldfusion JSON

Tags: json, coldfusion

Currently I'm getting this output (QueryBean):

[image: Image of serialized query]

But I want the "normal" JSON output, like this one:

```
[
  {
    "EventType": "active",
    "InstanceId": "6728E65C-XXXX-XXXXX",
    "CustomerId": "1000324234",
    "Name": "bilderbuchverein Hermsen"
    "Amount": 999999,
    "StartDate": "August, 01 2019 00:00:00",
    "ExpirationDate": null
  },
  {
    "EventType": "active",
    "InstanceId": "956FA492-XXXX-XXXXX",
    "Name": "Phantasialand"
    "CustomerId": "12345678999",
    "Amount": 123456789,
    "StartDate": "August, 14 2019 00:00:00",
    "ExpirationDate": null
  }
]
```

How can I manage to change the output format? My function has the parameter `produces="application/json"`

```
<cffunction name="listEvents" access="remote" returnType="any" produces="application/JSON" httpmethod="GET" restpath="/events">
    <cfquery datasource="hostmanager" name="plannedInstances">
    SELECT * FROM licenses
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn plannedInstances>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: @Ageax Yes, I've added my code

Comment: @dewey Your combinedQueries query comes from where ?  I could not able to see any query like that ?

Comment: @Kannan.P ups sorry, I've corrected it

Comment: When you return a query, it will serialize that, which is what you’re seeing in your output. If you want the json format you specified, you need to build your own data structure after executing the query to match what you want your json to be, and return that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get JSON output data as an array of structure, you can use Application-level defining. In `Application.cfc` by adding `this.serialization.serializeQueryAs = "struct"` you can get serialize JSON output data as an array of structure like below.

```
[
  {
    "CATEGORYID":20,
    "CATEGORYNAME":"php",
    "CATEGORYDESC":"php"
  },
  {
    "CATEGORYID":21,
    "CATEGORYNAME":"cf",
    "CATEGORYDESC":"cf"
  },
  {
    "CATEGORYID":22,
    "CATEGORYNAME":".Net",
    "CATEGORYDESC":".net"
  }
]
```

I have used the same code with my test table. (please see the example code result screenshot)[image]

Also, you can refer [SerializeJSON](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/serializejson.html) 'Additional format for query serialization' I think you can't able to handle this issue with `produces="application/json"`

I hope It's useful for you!

Comment: This made me thinking so I found `serializeJSON(plannedInstances, "struct")`. This is now my solution and propably works the same like your method!

Comment: @dewey happy to hear that

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps to achieve your goal.

1. Create and return an array of structures instead of a query ( Which fully based on CFML side )
2. Use the **ParseJson** method in jQuery to parse the response from CF.

Here is an example of returning an array of structures in JSON format. It creates a single array, and populates it with individual structures inside the query loop. Insert the query column names as the structure key, and finally append the structure into the root array. Finally, return that array from the function.

```
<cffunction name="sampleCall"  access="remote" returntype="any" returnformat="JSON">

        <cfquery name="read" datasource="myDataSource">
            SELECT * FROM myTable limit 10
        </cfquery>
        <cfset myArray = [] >
        <cfloop query="read">
            <cfset myStr = {} >
            <cfset structInsert(myStr, "logid", read.logid)>
            <cfset structInsert(myStr, "log_datetime", read.log_datetime)>
            <cfset structInsert(myStr, "log_Details", read.log_Details)>
            <cfset arrayAppend(myArray,myStr)>
        </cfloop>
        <cfreturn myArray / >
    </cffunction>
```

**Note :** The example uses sample columns from my query. You can use your own column names.

If you dump  the result like the image below

[image: image of results]